# Can re-rendering of all inputs be avoided when passing a whole object?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, rendering

I have quite a few different interfaces with many properties like

```
interface IEntity1 {
    a: string
    b: number
    c: string
    ....
}
```

When I want to edit an object (i.e., create a modified copy), I can do

```
function Editor(props: {entity: IEntity1, setEntity(e: IEntity1) => void}) {
    const {entity, setEntity} = props;
    const [a, setA] = useState(entity.a);
    const [b, setB] = useState(entity.a);
    ....
    function handleOk() {
       setEntity({a, b, c, ...});
    }

    return <div>
       <input value={a} onChange={e => setA(e.target.value}/>
       <input value={''+b} onChange={e => setB(+e.target.value}/>
       <input value={c} onChange={e => setC(e.target.value}/>
       ...
       <button onClick={handleOk}>OK</button>
    </div>;
}
```

This works fine, but it's pretty repetitive. So I created a "universal" component, which can handle number, string and other inputs. Using it, I can handle all fields in a loop like

```
{fieldNames.map(f => <Edit value={entity[f]}
                       onChange={newValue => setEntity({...entity}, {[f]: newValue})}/>)}
```

I can generate all the needed metadata (above for simplicity just `fieldNames: string[]`) easily. I can do even better with

```
{fieldsMetadata.map(f => <Edit2 entity={entity} field={f}/>)}
```

where `Edit2` is a "smarter" component. *What bothers me is that* all *my edits get re-rendered on* any *change.* This may be a premature optimization, but given that I want to use this component many time on many pages, it may be a valid concern.

*So I'm asking whether it's possible to write such a component without it re-rendering every time or whether there's something performance-relevant what I'm missing?*

Comment: Functional components will rerender children whenever they render. You may be able to use PureComponents or the `memo` HOC with functional components to hint to react to skip renders based upon a caparison of previous and next props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in with your component re-rendering is because on passing the inline arrow function which is created again on every render

Once you avoid it you can implement each Edit component with React.memo or PureComponent depending on whether you implement it as a functional component or class

```
const onChange= useCallback((name, value) => {
     setEntity(prev => ({...prev, [name]: value}));
}, []);
 ...
{fieldNames.map(f => <Edit name={f} value={entity[f]}
                       onChange={onChange}/>)}
```

and Edit component would be like

```
const Edit = (props) => {
    const {value, name, setEntity} = props;
    const handleChange = (e) => {
         const newValue = e.target.value;
         onChange(name, newValue);
    }

    return <input value={value} name={name} onChange={handleChange} />

}

export default React.memo(Edit)
```

P.S Make sure you are merging the state correctly with setEntity

Comment: Are you sure about the empty deps of the `useCallback` hook? I did something similar and got a broken component, where editing one field led to changes to other field being lost.

Comment: @maaartinus Yes the empty dependency is correct. state updates need to be merged correctly. Look at how I did it in my post